# Variational method when the Hamiltonian commutes with the parity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, parity

Why can we apply the variational method to determine the first excited state of a system when the Hamiltonian commutes with the parity operator? Ignoring the information about the commutation, it seems to me that the inequality we need to be able to apply the method isn't satisfied in general, because we would be using the previous calculations related to the fundamental level, which are already an approximation. Why is the parity operator relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the first excited level is the lowest energy state  that is orthogonal to the ground state. The ground state is symmetric under $x\to-x$ and the first excited state is antisymmetric. So, if we explore the  energy-expectations of  state that are  antisymmetric, the trial states are orthogonal to the ground state and  the lowest energy one will be the first excited state.